# Why function changes type?

Tags: swift, core-data

During my investigation I discovered strange behavior with Swift, but maybe I don’t understand something.

I made small object to test:

```
class BugTest:NSObject {
    func test<Type>(content:[Type]) {

        func inside<Head, Tail>(object:Head, type:Tail.Type) {
            print ("Head: \(Head.self), Tail: \(Tail.self)")
        }

        if let first = content.first {
            print("first element type: \(type(of: first)) Type.self: \(Type.self)")
            inside(object:first, type:type(of:first))
        }
    }
}
```

The result is strange; once it recognizes `<Type>` as Joint, this case listing is nice:

```
first element type: Joint Type.self: Joint
Head: Joint, Tail: Joint
```

But sometimes not:

```
first element type: Point Type.self: NSManagedObject
Head: NSManagedObject, Tail: NSManagedObject
```

If I print type(of: first) Point is printed, but if I pass type as type(of: first) it changes to `NSManagedObject` inside the `func inside`.

Any idea how to pass type and not lose it?

The code which called BugTest.test(content:[T]) looked something like this:

```
//Defned in model
// Not real one

class Foo:NSMnagedObject {
    var braus:[Bar]
}
class Bar:Foo  {
    var cirrus:[Car]
    var stratus:[Whatever]
}
class Car:Bar {
    var dudu:[Whatever]
}

//...etc...

func goDeeper<T>(content: [T]) {

    let pathToNext = GethNicePath() \\ was OK
    if let firstObject = content.first {

        let bugtest = BugTest()
        bugtest(content)

        let nextSet = firstObject[KetPath: pathToNext]
        goDeeper(nextSet)

    }
}
```

First iteration was OK, but all next `type(of: first)` returned NSManagedObcject.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to call the `BugTest.test()` function?

Comment: I put some meta code.  I think it's a feature of Swift. I ”solved” it by sending particular Foo.self instead type(of:). which made program more complicated.

Comment: I attempted to post an answer that would go along the lines of what you're saying. I suspect `type(of:)` returns the first type representation it finds on the binary metadata, whereas a generic function will default to the lowest type it finds when the compiler tries to infer what type is expected to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes — ”type(of:) returns the first type representation it finds on the binary metadata, whereas a generic function will default to the lowest type it finds when the compiler tries to infer what type is expected to be returned”